# window builder exported jar: why does it look different from in eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, windowbuilder

in eclipse i did set the window size / colors and testing the look in linux ubuntu eclipse.
after i exported it to a runnable jar, the colors are completely wrong: background color yellow became black.
the sizes of the fields are much bigger than defined.
Anybody can tell me why that happens and what needs to be changed?

Comment: What technology are you using, SWT or Swing?

Comment: i am using SWT.
I also found out by adding the swt.gtk 4.3 will improve the display in ubuntu. but need to use web safe color. Furthermore in eclipse it still does look different (i need to use GTK 2 in ini because the default GTK3 messes up with the perspective menues). Now the problem is that designing in eclipse looks different than running it outside eclipse. Any ides how to get it show correctly in eclipse other than using the f*cked up GTK 3 default?

Answer (score 0):

ok my workaround:
develop and test with eclipse build path settings using GTK in eclipse.ini:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36V9l.jpg)

export build path for ubuntu GTK3 (it will look like GTK 2 in eclipse):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOrrF.jpg)

If there is a better way, please let me know.